# Positioning things with respect to axis of a pgfplot in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a figure on an `axis` and want to add descriptive text and signs to it with `tikz`. However, I need to do the alignment of the text with respect to the axis by visually observing if it matches. Is there a way to tell `tikz` to use the alignment with respect to the axis. I tried using `(axis cs:x,y)` command but did not help.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10cm,
            height=4cm,
            x axis line style={-stealth},
            y axis line style={-stealth},
            title={this is my title},
            xticklabels={},
            ymax = 1.5, xmax=7.5,
            axis lines*=center,
            ytick={1},
            xlabel={f},
            ylabel={H(f)},
            xlabel near ticks,
            ylabel near ticks,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south}
            ]
            \addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
            coordinates
            {(0,0) (4,1) (5,0) (7,0)};
        \end{axis}
        % I want this to be aligned with axis' 4 and 5
        \draw[<->] (4.0,-0.3) -- (5.0,-0.3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To use `axis cs` (which is the default with `compat=1.11` or newer I think), you hace to place the `\draw` command inside the `axis` environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It indeed works as expected. However, the figure is not automatically resized when `draw` command draws below axis. Is there a right way of doing it other than manually setting the height?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help found the answer to the second question and wanted to write here for completeness. Adding `clip=false` to the axis properties solves that issue too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `axis cs` outside an `axis` environment will not work, as there is no current `axis`. Hence, just move the `\draw` command inside the axis and add `axis cs:` and it will align as you want it. Since version 1.11 of `pgfplots` the `axis cs` coordinate system is used by default, if `compat=1.11` (or higher) is specified in `\pgfplotsset`.

As you saw, objects placed outside the axis area are clipped away by default. You can disable clipping by adding `clip=false` to the axis options, but this will also disable clipping of plots that go outside the defined axis limits (`xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`). If you instead introduce `clip mode=individual`, plots will be clipped, while additional `\draw` commands and similar will *not* be clipped.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10cm,
            height=4cm,
            x axis line style={-stealth},
            y axis line style={-stealth},
            title={this is my title},
            xticklabels={},
            ymax = 1.5, xmax=7.5,
            axis lines*=center,
            ytick={1},
            xlabel={f},
            ylabel={H(f)},
            xlabel near ticks,
            ylabel near ticks,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
            clip mode=individual
            ]
            \addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
            coordinates
            {(0,0) (4,1) (5,0) (7,0)};

        \draw[<->] (axis cs:4.0,-0.3) -- (axis cs:5.0,-0.3);
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% with compat=1.11 or newer the axis cs coordinate system is used by default
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=10cm,
            height=4cm,
            x axis line style={-stealth},
            y axis line style={-stealth},
            title={this is my title},
            xticklabels={},
            ymax = 1.5, xmax=7.5,
            axis lines*=center,
            ytick={1},
            xlabel={f},
            ylabel={H(f)},
            xlabel near ticks,
            ylabel near ticks,
            every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},anchor=south},
            clip mode=individual
            ]
            \addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
            coordinates
            {(0,0) (4,1) (5,0) (7,0)};
        \draw[<->] (4.0,-0.3) -- (5.0,-0.3);
        \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```